# Long pressing an item on Android Chrome shows the context menu for a bit but then shows up an unwanted drag-and-drop item

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, long-press

For example, when I long press an item, it shows the context menu but then the context menu gets closed a tiny bit after and summons a drag-and-drop box (containing the URL and the name of the page if it's a link, if it's an image it then just shows the floating image). It shows the item like I'm dragging it, but I am actually not. When the floating item is present, it doesn't let me touch any other links or anything on screen. If I let go my finger quick enough, it stays still for some seconds and then it just disappears with a very slight movement to the bottom. I just have to wait for it to disappear to finally touch anything else. If I drag it for a bit and then I let go my finger, it disappears normally.

It's annoying because I have to let go my finger quick enough to actually be able to tap the context menu.

It's even more annoying because I can't do a single thing with the floating link, not even move it from tab to tab, just drag it pointlessly through the screen.

Also, it overlays all displays on-screen, even the "Shutting down" screen, and sometimes it gets completely stuck on screen, that means I can tap everything else when it's ghost overlay is present, and even be able to see 2 of these floating things on screen (the second one being a non-ghost box), but the only way to get rid of that ghost overlay is by resetting the device. Also, the ghost overlay can even appear on the lock screen.

Note: This is not made by me in any way, as I don't have any programming knowledge. This is just a really annoying thing that I found lately that I want you to help me with.

I don't even know if it was whether a WebView update bug, a malware, a screen bug or anything so I don't know. Please help me. This was the closest source of help to resort to.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Android Enthusiasts or Superuser instead? In my annoyance with this problem and the nice solution, I neglected to consider that when I set the bounty. Oh well: a much needed solution in the wrong place can potentially be better than a much needed solution in no place.

Answer (score 4):

I disabled "Simultaneous touch drag and context menu" in chrome://flags/

It solved my problem with longpress and link open context menu

Comment: Solved the problem for me (which just started happening today on Android 10, when long-pressing links--not regular text).

Comment: It is not related to Android version but Chrome version. Extremely annoying setting. That employee (who set it as default) should be fired.

Comment: I think the equivalent in desktop chrome is "WebUI tab strip context menu after tap", but it only disables multi-touch long press. There's still context menu on single touch long press. Any idea how to disable for single touch long press?

Comment: Has this been removed from the flags menu? I can't find this same thing in the flags menu.